# Vue JSX Transform: Duplicate declaration "h" (This is an error on an internal node. Probably an internal error)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jsx

Working on a table that is using: https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2

For a column of the table I want to return some JSX to show an element that will be styled with CSS.

I've used this method before, as the docs say, and its worked fine but on this project i'm getting:

Duplicate declaration "h" (This is an error on an internal node. Probably an internal error)

The template that is being returned is:

```
templates: {
    status: function (h) {
        return <i class = "cssIcon">< /i>
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/jsx/issues/34#issuecomment-479816621

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@vue/app'],
  plugins: ['jsx-v-model']
}
```

The plugins can not includes 'transform-vue-jsx', if presets has '@vue/app'.